# RegExp for Postal Code, faster/better way?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following pattern to match Canadian postal codes.  Is there a better way?

```
const zip = new RegExp(/[a-z][\d][a-z][\s]?[\d][a-z][\d]/, 'gi');

console.log(zip.test("L1K 4W2"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression is likely not the bottleneck in your code, so you shouldn't worry about performance.

However, a common mistake is not *anchoring* the regular expression. Your regular expression will match any string that just *contains* a matching pattern. Example:

```js
const zip = new RegExp(/[a-z][\d][a-z][\s]?[\d][a-z][\d]/, 'gi');

console.log(zip.test("123123123L1K 4W2123123123"));
```

Often this is not the desired behavior. Anchor your expression at the beginning and end of the string, or at least on *word boundaries*.

A couple of syntax/style remarks:

- There is no need to use character classes for single characters. `[\d]` etc should just be `\d`.
- You are using the `RegExp` constructor incorrectly. It expects a **string**, not a regular expression literal. There is no need to use the constructor here.
- There is no need for the `g` flag if all you are doing is testing for a match. `g` is useful if you want to extract all matches.

With all that said:

```js
// Match whole string
let zip = /^[a-z]\d[a-z]\s?\d[a-z]\d$/i;

console.log(zip.test('123L1K 4W2123')); // false
console.log(zip.test('123 L1K 4W2 123')); // false
console.log(zip.test('L1K 4W2')); // true

// Match word boundaries 
zip = /\b[a-z]\d[a-z]\s?\d[a-z]\d\b/i;

console.log(zip.test('123L1K 4W2123')); // false
console.log(zip.test('123 L1K 4W2 123')); // true
console.log(zip.test('L1K 4W2')); // true
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a big miss. Plus using g flag and RegExp incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

`[A-z]\d[A-z]\s?\d[A-z]\d` is better.

`a-z` only covers small letters. To include capital letters, you have to use `A-z`. And \d and \s don't need [].

Comment: i flag makes the regex case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

In Canada, character 1 of the postal code can only be A, B, C, E, G, H, J, K, L, M, N, P, R, S, T, V, X, Y. The letters D, F, I, O, Q and U are not used in any part of the postal code. So a more accurate, though clumsier, regex expression to validate them would be:

`\A(A|B|C|E|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|P|R|S|T|V|X|Y)[0-9](A|B|C|E|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|P|R|S|T|V|W|X|Y|Z)( )[0-9](A|B|C|E|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|P|R|S|T|V|W|X|Y|Z)[0-9]\Z`

See https://www.grcdi.nl/gsb/canada.html#HDE30744DF5A20A8C74F4A30166A00D3504659EB203FCanadaA20A2DA20A5BA5BPostalA20codeA20regularA20expressionA5DA5D00700A00D01001301C02302D03A03D